# Android game development in C#

Tags: c#, java, android, mono

I want to know, is there any way to develop games for Android-based mobiles (and maybe iPhone) in **C#**? Yep, i know about "*MonoDroid/Mono for Android*", but well... it's not free. **Java** is great but *Dalvik* performance is far worse than *Mono*. And it lacks of some features that are very useful for game development such as operator overloading. Furthermore, there is *OpenTK* framework which is simply amazing.

So, is it possible to get running *.NET/Mono* on *Android* ***for free***? Or am I sentenced to **Java**?

Comment: I don't know how you can suggest that using Java is a 'sentance'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to be able install unmanaged code on the device. I would recommend using Java, because I can foresee deployment being difficult with mono. Google might not let you sell your app on their marketplace with large quantities of unmanaged code. It would also tie you down to Android phones sporting a particular brand of processor, not much of a problem as all of the phones I can think of use ARM processors but there are some exceptions.

You could try http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:ARM if you are sure about this.

Operator overloading is simply syntactic sugar. I'm sure you are capable of writing applications without it. And Java can't be without its own suitable frameworks surely.

Android is overflowing with java and its most likely easier not to try and fight it.

Comment: -1 For disallowing unmanaged code.  They have the NDK which is all done in C/C++ which is unmanaged.  Also using C# wouldn't lock you to a specific processor since it gets compiled to an Intermediate Language (IL) and Just In Time (JIT) compiled by the interpreter.

Comment: The IL itself wouldn't be the problem. The runtime that you would bundle would have be specific to the processor and there lies the difficulties. There is also a Mono:MIPS project but that looks a lot less functional. I was thinking that Google might have some security concerns with large bodies of unmanaged code, especially ones that write to memory and then execute from it, but it seems they really will rubber-stamp anything.

Comment: for loops and if statements are just syntactic sugar. You really should just develop everything in Assembly like a man.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Java then you should use the NDK and C/C++; especially for games.  An additional upside to that is if you think ahead a bit you can have a large chunck of code that works on Android and iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I am not normally a fan of offering something outside the limits of what you've set, but you should take this advice to heart:

If you are serious about Game Development I would invest time in learning [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/unity/). The non Pro version is free and does not expire. They have iPhone and Android kits that allow you to deploy your game on both of those platforms. Yes they do cost money, but start calculating how much your time is worth.

If you are doing this as an exercise to learn how Game Engines work then that is awesome and you should pursue it. If you are more focused on developing an actual game, look into one of the existing kits. Unity3d is by far the easiest and cheapest kit for all the features it has.